# How to convert the following table to JSON with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, html-table, cypress

I have the following table and want to convert it into JSON in a specific way

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My expected output would be like this as I need to compare the data over UI in html table and a json file having expected data (Note: there may be a varying number of rows):

```
{
  "myrows" : [
    {
      "Column 1" : "A1",
      "Column 2" : "A2",
      "Column 3" : "A3"
    },
    {
      "Column 1" : "B1",
      "Column 2" : "B2",
      "Column 3" : "B3"
    },
    {
      "Column 1" : "C1",
      "Column 2" : "C2",
      "Column 3" : "C3"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward to loop over rows then cells in the row.

Use index values from `each()` command to give you access to the expected value in the JSON.

```js
const expected = { "myrows" : [
  ...  // as in the question, abreviated here
]}

it('check the table', () => {
  cy.get('table tbody tr').each(($row, rowIndex) => {
    cy.wrap($row).find('td').each(($cell, cellIndex) => {
      const text = $cell.text()
      expect(text).to.eq(expected.myrows[rowIndex][`Column ${cellIndex}`]
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

const result = {
  myrows: []
};
rows.forEach(r => {
  const rData = {}
  r.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((c, i) => {
    rData[`column_${i + 1}`] = c.innerHTML;
  })
  result.myrows.push(rData)
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>B3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

following approach I have followed, taking reference from  answer given by "Genevieve OR" on my post, Thanks to @Genevieve OR

```
var headerList = []
cy.get('table thead tr th').each(($el)=>{
      var headerName = $el.text()
      headerList.push(headerName)// dynamically make a list of header
)}.then(()=>{
      var jsonData = [];
  
      cy.get('table tbody').find('tr').each(($row, rowIndex) => {
             jsonData[rowIndex] = {};// creates object for each row
             cy.wrap($row).find('td').each(($cell, cellIndex) => {
                const text = $cell.text()
                jsonData[rowIndex][headerList[cellIndex]] = text
                const expected = { "myrows" :jsonData}
            
            })
       })
})
```

My output

```
{
  "myrows": [
    {
      "column_1": "A1",
      "column_2": "A2",
      "column_3": "A3"
    },
    {
      "column_1": "B1",
      "column_2": "B2",
      "column_3": "B3"
    },
    {
      "column_1": "C1",
      "column_2": "C2",
      "column_3": "C3"
    }
  ]
}
```